# Nservicebus move Timeout Message across different boxes

Tags: nservicebus

We are trying to do a server move on  same version of NSB but moving to a different box.

Need to move some timeout messages. Timeout messages have a response address (the endpoint it has to go back to), what is the best way to move these. Couple of options I saw

1) Use Queue explorer import them and edit the response manually. It gets unmanagable if we have more than 100 timeout messages. I have verified this works.

2) I tried using some code from Andreas latest timeout message move from (2.6 to 3.0), looks like underlying deseralizer has changed. I get:  "Root element is missing", when trying to read the body. I tried deserializing it to both TimeoutData and Timeoutmessage.

3) I setup an endpoint to listen for TimeoutMessage and use mutator to change the header to destination endpoint, this seems to be working, but timeoutmessages are not taken off the queue after they are processed.

So, with that I am stuck with 1 and I want some automated process around it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andreas, 
Thanks for the response. I went back and worked on my 3rd solution. I listen to timeoutmessage, use DestinationOverride to mutate to new address and do a bus.Send to the timeout endpoint.

I had to add DonotCOntinueDispatchingCUrrentMessageToHandlers to remove timeout message from queue.

This is what my code looks like

```
public void Handle(TimeoutMessage message)
    {

        DestinationOverride.CurrentDestination = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResponseQueue"];

        var header = message.GetHeader("CorrId");

        bus.Send<TimeoutMessage>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutputQueue"], tm =>
             {
                 tm.ClearTimeout = false; //always false since we don't store the "clear" requests
                 tm.Expires = message.Expires;
                 tm.SagaId = message.SagaId;
                 tm.State = message.State;
                 tm.SetHeader("CorrId",header);
             });

        bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers();

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to modify the existing TimeoutMigrator

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/master/src/tools/migration/TimeoutMigrator

And take a look at your current TimeoutData in reflector or by looking at the contents in the storage queue.

Then modify the TimeoutData class in the migrator to match your current schema:

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/tools/migration/TimeoutMigrator/TimeoutData.cs